# NUnit async tests fail after merge

Tags: c#, async-await, nunit, nunit-2.6

NUnit 2.6.4.

I have a VS/C# project that introduces async methods. It has many tests like this that pass:

```
    [Test]
    public async void NullProcThrows_Async()
    {
        var keyList = new KeyList<int>();
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(async () => await keyList.LoadAsync((IDBProcedure)null, "ID", CancellationToken.None));
    }
```

I have merged this into our trunk (no conflicts) and now this test fails. I am trying to figure out the difference.

When I trace the code in the trunk I see two exceptions thrown:

The first is the ArgumentNullException I am expecting.
The second is

```
NUnit.Framework.AssertionException saying Expected
<System.ArgumentNullException> But was:  null
```

When I run the test on the branch version I only see the one exception and the test passes.

What could be different between the two projects?

Comment: What did you merge?

Comment: It sounds like you're passing an `async void` lambda.

Comment: Have you compared the code on your branch with the trunk to see what's different? It's highly likely that the merge "failed" (in the sense of merging the wrong code) and a diff will show up what it replaced incorrectly.

Comment: `now this test fails` - on your CI server running a different version of NUnit? The NUnit semantics around `async void` methods have changed more than once.

Comment: This branch added some async versions of sync methods on repositories. The to/from code is identical, as far as I can tell. In this case, LoadAsync has this method: public async Task LoadAsync(IDBProcedure p, string keyColumnName, CancellationToken ct)

Comment: Well now that's spooky. I forced VS to get-latest from TFS overwriting files even if it thought they were the same and now the tests pass.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a few issues with the code provided, consider the following:

```
[Test, ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException)]
public async Task NullProcThrows_Async()
{
    var keyList = new KeyList<int>();
    await keyList.LoadAsync((IDBProcedure)null, "ID", CancellationToken.None);
    Assert.Fail("This should never be executed as we expected the above to throw.");
}
```

According to the `NUnit` documentation, you should be using the [`ExpectedException`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exception&r=2.6.4) attribute instead of `Assert.Throws`. So I added that attribute and then remove the `Assert.Throws` and instead add `Assert.Fail`. Also, I made the method `Task` returning and this prevented the `async void`. Finally, doing it this way prevents the `async lambda`.

Comment: Thank you David. I will consider this as an update. I was in a yank to get the merge successful after our release over the weekend. Everything tested fine in the branch and didn't in the trunk. so some bits must have been fiddled because a complete get-latest solved the problem.